# To forward-search in Raspbian's Bash?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, search

Keybinding `CTRL`-`S` is enabled by default in Debian/Ubuntu/OS X bun not in Raspbian. I can enable the reverse-search by in `$HOME/.bashrc`, which disables XON/XOFF, but it does not help with the forward-search

```
stty -ixon
```

I found in my old notes that you can do `bind s` in /etc/screenrc to disable the XON. Possibly, there is also some emulator in Raspbian that is preventing the forward search.

System: Raspbian Jessie (hash 64c7ed611929ea5178fbb69b5a5f29cc9cc7c157)
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3b

Comment: Raspbian works the same way as Ubuntu and OSX. If it isn't working, it's either because you used the wrong file (it should be `.bashrc` — but under the same circumstances that would also make it not work on Ubuntu) or because of something else you didn't tell us. If you can't get it to work: how are you launching bash — stty settings are *terminal* settings, so it matters whether you're using a console, a terminal emulator, SSH, etc.? Does `stty -a` indicate that `ixon` is on or off? What happens when you press Ctrl+S?

Comment: @Gilles When I press `CTRL`+`S`, nothing happens. `stty -ixon` disables XON/XOFF.